# where does windows vista hide the path environment variable?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, path

i think that's what i need? i'm not sure

i'm trying to run a command line program (BLAST, from NCBI) but it won't recognise the commands (blastall, formatdb, etc.) so i think i need to add the folder the bin is in to the path environment variable?

i think that's what i need to do? i think that's what it's called?

I think i've been shown this a few times, but i don't need to do it often, so i keep forgetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the My Computer icon on your desktop, right-click on it and choose `Properties`. There should be a `System Settings` or `Advanced System Settings` button, click that. You should get a dialog window. Click the `Advanced` tab, and then the `Environment Variables` button.

In the `System Variables` box, scroll down to the `Path` entry, and double-click that entry to edit it. You can paste the needed path at the beginning of the field, making sure to add a semicolon (**;**) after it.